# android how to capture only my log entries in the application programmatically

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

I want to get my log entries alone which i had put in the application and show it in the scrollable textview. For example

```
Log.e(SAMPLE_ACTIVITY_TAG, "App started")
```

I need those error logs alone and i dont want other unwanted logs. Is it possible by logcat command line tools ? I have tried the below code but i am getting complete application device logs

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line +"\n");
        }
        textView.setText(log.toString());
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create process object with below given command:

**logcat --pid=PID -d**

you need to replace PID with your application process id. process id can be fetched using below line of code

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
```

---

Your final source code should be like this. Please give it a try

```
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        String command = "logcat --pid="+pid+" -d";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line +"\n");
        }
        textView.setText(log.toString());
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```